# Use getters from SharedPreference Helper Class in Non - Activity Class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am an android beginner and tried almost every method to use Shared Preferences but when I try to get value in nonactivity class method doesn't work ONLY IF APP REMOVED FROM RECENT APPS.

My Scenario is like:

Class **LocationRequestHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class LocationRequestHelper {
    ...
    ...

    public static String getUserId() {
        return MainActivity.preferences.getString("userId","");
    }

    public static void setUserId(String userId) {
        MainActivity.preferences.edit().putString("userId", userId ).commit();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        public static SharedPreferences preferences;


            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        LocationRequestHelper.setUserId("1");

        ....
        ....
```

**Utils**

```
public class Utils {


    public static void getLocationUpdates(final Context context, final Intent intent, String broadcastevent){
        LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        if (result != null) {
            List<Location> locations = result.getLocations();
            Location firstLocation = locations.get(0);

            accuracy = firstLocation.getAccuracy();
            LocationData data = new LocationData();

            // MY FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK HERE    
            data.setUsrid(LocationRequestHelper.getUserId());
            updateServer(data);
        }
    }
```

getLocationUpdates is called from **BroadcastReceiver**

Now problems appears after I try to get userID using

```
   LocationRequestHelper.getUserId();
```

EDITED : Added Broadcast code

**LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "LUBroadcastReceiver";
    public static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES ="PROCESS_UPDATES";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES.equals(action)) {
                Utils.getLocationUpdates(context,intent,"PROCESS_UPDATES");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***NOTE:: THIS WORKS FINE IF APP IS IN BACKGROUND. BUT CRASHES AFTER I KILL FROM RECENT APPS.***

Please tell me how I can send saved user id in my api call?

sorry for caps but this is main problem :P

Comment: did u unregister your broadcast receiver in destroy of your Class

Comment: @santoXme i want broadcast to call method which is using userid value. So why to unregister it?

Comment: when u remove the application from the background at that time you have to unregister broadcast. Until the application is in the background no need to unregister  the receiver  .and after kill application i dont think u need the user id val anywhere

Comment: Whilst the stuff about broadcast receivers is true the reason the app is crashing is that static variables will all be null after the app is killed.  Also it's probably leaking memory.  Don't use static variables for this

Comment: May I ask what exception does the app throw when it crashes? I think you get NullPointerException because MainActivity is null when the app is killed

Comment: @jolly.exe  are u getting leaked IntentReceiver exception

Comment: Added broadcast code @Jahnold  this can be the issue. Can any body guid me how to hold saved values and which context to use while using SharedPreference ?

Comment: @AloDev I am unable to track issue ad debugger stops when app is killed from recent

Answer (score 0):

The reason the app is crashing is that when it is killed any static variables become `null`.  However you are still trying to access the SharedPreferences from the broadcast receiver and as such are getting a NPE.

The first thing you can do is update your `LocationRequestHelper` class to accept a context in the method rather than using the static SharedPreferences:

```
public class LocationRequestHelper {
    //...

    public static String getUserId(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getString("userId","");
    }

    public static void setUserId(Context context, String userId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefs.edit().putString("userId", userId ).commit();
    }
}
```

Then update you `MainActivity` to get rid of the SharedPrefs business and change the call to:

```
LocationRequestHelper.setUserId(this, "1");
```

And the `Utils` class to:

```
data.setUsrid(context, LocationRequestHelper.getUserId());
```